# How to get image date,location,size,orientation in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

When i click a photo in my photo gallery,it will go to another view controller with xip and show this image in xip. There is also a detail button.When detail button is pressed then I want to show the creation  date,location size,image path,camera information and white balance of the selected image on that xip.

Please help me how can I do this in objective c.

Comment: Please show evidence of the research carried out, the code you have implemented and the exact issue you are experiencing ... please review [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you use storyboard or xib?

Comment: Yes,I will show these information in a xip

Answer (score 0):

**Dont forgot to add frame work in build phase**

```
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>



- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

NSURL *refURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

 // define the block to call when we get the asset based on the url (below)
   ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *imageAsset)
{
ALAssetRepresentation *imageRep = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];
NSLog(@"[imageRep filename] : %@", [imageRep filename]);
};

// get the asset library and fetch the asset based on the ref url (pass in block above)
ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:refURL resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:nil];

}
```